# How to make local mobile device visible for CI tool

Tags: android, mobile, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am building automation project and want to run tests automatically on local mobile device, that connected to my machine. For that I uploaded my project to GitLab, created .yml file with commands in CI/CD and created schedule.

The next chalenge:
to run tests automatically, on mobile device connected to my machine.

Is any options to make local device visible for GitLab CI/CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your local machine, [install the gitlab-runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) and [register it to your GitLab project](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/). In order to use the device, you'll need to use the [`shell` executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html). Be sure to specify at least one unique tag for the runner (say, `android` for example)

In your yaml, add the tag you used for your runner in the `tags:` key. For example:

```
myjob:
  tags:
    - android
  script:
  # ...
```

This will make sure that only your runner will pick up the job.